# Is it possible to apply videoStabilize to YouTube videos through the V3 API?

Tags: youtube-api

I noticed in the [V3 API under Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) there is a parameter called: suggestions.editorSuggestions[].

One of the items it takes is videoStabilize – The video appears shaky and could be stabilized.

Would this actually stabilize the video through the API or just offer it as a suggestion to the video owner? If the latter is there a way to stabilize through the API?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the API response will offer that suggestion, but not let you act on it.

That being said... [this upcoming Google I/O session](https://developers.google.com/events/io/2013/sessions/325566030) is relevant to your question.